# Addition of 1st row and 2nd row then 2nd row and 3rd row.. using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SqlServer, which has one column

E.g.:

```
AvgCall

6.25
6.25
10
12.5
24.5
6
9
3
```

Now by using this data I want the result as shown below.

```
AvgCall                        NewColumn

6.25                           6.25
6.25                           12.5
10                             16.25
12.5                           22.5
24.5                           37
6                              30.5
9                              15
3                              12
```

So in the output NewColumn is added by the logic i.e. first row data as first row, then addition of first row + Second row then second row + third row.

how to get my result?

Comment: please try formatting your text as we can understand your question better...

Comment: Please include DDL, expected results and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql

Comment: Actually it is the LAG function that is needed.

Comment: getting error as 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sqlserver 2012, you also can use lead like below

```
select col1,col1+lead(col1) over (order by <<some orderring col>>)
from 
tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL version **LOWER** than 2012 use this:

```
; WITH T(Nums) as
    (
    SELECT 6.25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6.25
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12.5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 24.5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    ), Main as
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) Id,  * 
    FROM T
    )

    SELECT a.Nums , A.Nums +  ISNULL((SELECT MAX(b.Nums) FROM Main b WHERE b.Id =  a.Id-1 ),0) Col
    FROM Main a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use LAG

```
    create table #tmp(AvgCall FLOAT)

    insert into #tmp
    SELECT 6.25
    union ALL
    SELECT 6.25
    union ALL
    SELECT 10
    union ALL
    SELECT 12.5
    union ALL
    SELECT 24.5
    union ALL
    SELECT 6
    union ALL
    SELECT 9
    union ALL
    SELECT 3

    ;with cte
    AS( 
        Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum, * from #tmp 
    )

    select AvgCall+ISNULL(LAG(AvgCall) OVER(order by rownum),0)
    from cte

    drop table #tmp
```